ArcGIS Pro Spatial Join not joining
I keep getting all NULL's for the attribute fields I attempt to add from a polygon layer to a point layer using a spatial join, whether I use the tool in the Data Management tool box or right-click the point layer.  Nothing is joining even though they are in the same projection and no multipart features.  The points were originally KML, converted to point feature classes (I have 2 point feature classes, neither of which is working with the spatial join.  Any ideas?


Make sure there are no definition queries on the layer (and no other joins).  These can sometimes cause unexpected join issues (although I believe this many-years-old bad behaviour is supposed to have bene fixed in Pro 3.4?).

Thanks for helping troubleshoot.  No, there aren't any definition queries.

Try select all records in polygon

Thanks FelixIP.  I just tried selecting all records and still no luck.  Any other ideas?
